# Как правильно сделать сессии на PHP с возможностью запоминания?

Tags: php, mysql

Я использую, на сколько знаю, простейший вариант:

```
$query = queryMysql("SELECT email,login,pass FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) $error = 'Ошибка авторизации';
            else {
                $log_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $_SESSION['login'] = $log_q['login'];
                header("location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                exit;
            }
```

Но в форме у меня будет чекбокс "Запомнить?". Сейчас в любом случае после перезапуска браузера сессия уничтожается. Если чекбокс будет отмечен, то сессия не должна убиваться после закрытия браузера и вообще висеть, пока пользователь не нажмет кнопку "выход".

Я что то нагуглил по теме ini_set, но вообще не понял, что, как и для чего.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделаю такую фичу. Заранее спасибо!

---

Проще говоря, как сделать сессию пользователя пожизненной, как это сделано на большинстве сайтов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вспомните про куки. Они как раз и будут решением вашей проблемы. Только помните, что в куках нельзя хранить пароль в "сыром" виде.

Comment: А зачем пароль хранить там? Если связка логин и пароль подходят, то ставим логин в куки и все. Или это одна большая дыра безопасности?)

Comment: @inferus-vv там не пароль нужно хранить, а его хеш. На вашем месте я бы пару логин-хеш, пароль-хеш хранил в одной нераздельной строке с каким-нибудь дополнительным шифрованием, о котором знаете только вы  ;) при заходе пользователя на сайт, сначала смотрите, существует ли у него сессия. Если нет - смотрите на куку, если существует и подходит определенным требованиям (которые вы выставляете), то разбираете куку и в базе ищете юзера с данным набором логин-хеш, пароль-хеш.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю зачем хеш)

Comment: @inferus-vv чтобы лишний раз не светить данные пользователя)

Comment: Если не затруднит, можно, пожалуйста, пример генерации хеша, что туда записывать и в каких случаях считывать?

Comment: про md5 или sha-x слышали? Про всё остальное я написал уже :)

Comment: Конечно :) Я про другое. Что сравнивать с бд и в каких случаях

Comment: При создании записи пользователя в бд генерируете отдельный хеш логина. В куку записываете что-нибудь вроде: "бякаЛогин-хешБякаmd5(Пароль-хеш)". Если сессии авторизации не существует, смотрим куку, как я уже и говорил. Потом ищем в БД юзера по логину-хешу. Если такая запись есть, то достаем пароль-хеш из БД, еще раз хешируем его и сравниваем с записью в куке. Лол, для параноиков специально :D

Answer (score 1):

Пожизненной её не сделать поскольку браузеры автоматом через какой то период удаляют куки. Вам нужно сделать в БД ещё одну таблицу в которой хранить сессии авторизованных пользователей, а в куки хранить номер сессии.
Т.е. если куки нет, генерируем идентификатор сессии - `$sid`, пишем его в куку и далее используем `$sid` для проверки авторизован или нет посетитель. Если кука есть, берем из неё `$sid` и используем.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_COOKIE["sid"])) {
    $sid = session_id();
    setcookie ("sid", session_id(), time()+3600*48);
}
else {
    $sid = $_COOKIE["sid"];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
setcookie('email', $email);

<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['email'] ?>" />
```

Comment: Это пользовательская функция

Comment: Можно подробнее расписать, пожалуйста, как и где использовать?

Comment: что она делает?

Comment: следишь, отмечен ли твой чекбокс. если да, то устанавливаешь куку с помощью setcookie()

Comment: Вот и интересует этот момент, как устанавливать эту куку

Comment: каким образом? просто мне интересно... распиши эту функцию тут, если не трудно

Comment: Тут максимум 7 комментов к записи. Вот ф-я:

function queryMysql($query) {
 $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 return $query;
}